# Description of the following code?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do have a situation where a programmer who has developed a stored procedure is absent and doesn't work anymore, so I have to make a little bit of update to the code. I should add 2 more variables in to the code and I know the place, but I don't know how to put it.. Could you please describe the following code, what it does in terms of sql? Cause I know what for this code stand inside the programm..

```
RAISE NOTICE 'STAT CARD: formid=%',formid; 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_aggregation; 
--  execute 
    sql_ := 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_aggregation as ' --select programstageinstanceid,'|| dynamic_columns ||' from patientdatavalue'
        ||'
        select OrgUnitID
            , max(dateperiod) as dateperiod
            , programstageinstanceid
            , max("[DE:202062.202063.575]"::integer) as "[DE:202062.202063.575]"    
            , max(
                (case when position(''-'' in "[DE:202062.202063.202095]")>0 then substring("[DE:202062.202063.202095]" from 0 for position(''-'' in "[DE:202062.202063.202095]"))
                 else "[DE:202062.202063.202095]" end)
                 ) as "[DE:202062.202063.202095]" 
            , sum("[DE:202062.202063.202078]"::integer) as "[DE:202062.202063.202078]" 
            , max("[DE:202062.202063.202076]") as "[DE:202062.202063.202076]" 

        from 
        (
            select psi.organisationunitid as OrgUnitID
            , ou.name as OrgName, pdv.timestamp as DatePeriod
            , pdv.programstageinstanceid
            , pdv.dataelementid
            , pdv.value,'
            || dynamic_columns ||'          
            from patientdatavalue pdv inner join programstageinstance psi 
            on pdv.programstageinstanceid = psi.programstageinstanceid 
        --   left join organisationunit ou 
            inner join tbl_org_list ou 
            on psi.organisationunitid = ou.organisationunitid 

            where psi.completed=''t'' and 
            psi.duedate >= '''||period_from ||''' and 
            psi.duedate <= '''||period_to ||'''
        )as aggregation_
        '||cCondition||'
        group by programstageinstanceid, OrgUnitID 
        ';
```

In this code there are hard-coded "variables" as `[DE:202062.202063.575]`, and `[DE:202062.202063.202078]` and etc.. I do have 2 more different `[DE:xxx,xxx,xx]` which I should add here.

Because whenever I run this storing procedure it doesn't work and gives the error that those new `[DE:xxx,xxx,xx]` doesn't exist.. So I should make them exist in the code, but where to put them? TO do it I have to understand the sql syntax and what it does, and unfortunately I'm noob in sql.

Comment: ***stored procedure**

Comment: and i miss the definition of `dynamic_columns`

Comment: there is at least one more  "storing procedure"

Comment: @Aツ, it's only one big stored procedure, I just copy pasted the part which is responsible for doing what I need. Here is the definition of what you have asked `DECLARE dynamic_columns text;`